# ORACLE - Query to obtain records that are not in a particular date format

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with values:

```
-----------------------
ID  Date
-----------------------
1   2015-06-26
2   1974-05-29 00:00:00
3   2012-01-30 00:00:00
4   2011-12-03 00:00:00
5   1994-06-12
6   2016-04-01
-----------------------
```

I need to get those IDs which are **NOT** in the format `1974-05-29 00:00:00`.

i.e, my output should be:

```
-----------------------
ID  Date
-----------------------
1   2015-06-26
5   1994-06-12
6   2016-04-01
-----------------------
```

Please help.

**UPDATE**:
*Data type of date column* : VARCHAR2(128 CHAR)

Comment: data type of date column?

Comment: Please find the update Gaj.

Comment: ?simplest solution?: SELECT * FROM table WHERE LENGTH(date) <= 10

Comment: @Chriz How dumb I've been ! I was trying how to go with Regex ! This is way too good.

Comment: @Mike Sometimes we just need someone to talk to and all problems resolve themselves :D

Comment: Yes. That will work in every way ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Select * from my_table where instr(date, '00:00:00') <= 0

or 

Select * from my_table where length(date) = 10
```

Note: I'm not sure why you are maintain date in string format. Better try to convert to date format (if possible)

Comment: Thank you for your efforts Gaj

Answer (score 1):

You you only need to check the format, you can use:

```
select *
from yourTable
where not regexp_like("Date", '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}')
```

Please notice that this does not check the content, so a string like  `'2011-12-03 99:99:99'` would be considered correct.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts Aleksej